# Android Maps v2 destination box

Tags: android, android-layout, android-maps-v2

What is the best way that allows me to show "destination box" in Maps v2? Do you have any tips how to create a custom view of "destination box" (e.g is there a possibility to pass my custom layout to method that is responsible for showing destBox).
By destination box I meant:
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can put your map in a **Relative** layout and add the view programatically, I recommend relative layout because it support z-axis adding of view which means you can add view on top of each other.

The **view** that you will add  programatically will be aligned on the bottom of the `relative layout` and the **map** should have match parent as width and height so you can put the view on top of it just like the above.